# How to make sql nested/sub query in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm struggling with implementing SQL query into my php code.

The query:

```sql
select template_id, min(created_at) as created_at from (
select distinct 
root_template_id as template_id, 
date_created as created_at, 
response_id as response_id
from db.score
inner join db.users ON db.score.supplier_id = db.users.old_id
inner join db.acc ON db.acc.user_id = db.users.id
where db.acc.account_id = 25) as T
group by template_id
```

I was able to prepare only this part:

```php
$query = DB::table('score')
->selectRaw('DISTINCT root_template_id as template_id, date_created as created_at, response_id') 
->join('users', 'score.supplier_id', '=', 'users.old_id')
->join('acc', 'acc.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->whereIn('acc.account_id', $request->id)
```

And it works, but it is only responsible for the nested part, for the subquery if I can call it like this. Can someone share any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::table()` usually receive table name as a string, but it can also receive `Closure` or an `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instance, so this should do the trick for Laravel's select from subquery:

```php
DB::table(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->selectRaw('DISTINCT root_template_id as template_id, date_created as created_at, response_id')
    ->from('score')
    ->join('users', 'score.supplier_id', '=', 'users.old_id')
    ->join('acc', 'acc.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereIn('acc.account_id', $request->id)
}, 'T')
    ->select([
        'template_id',
        DB::raw("MIN(created_at) AS created_at"),
    ])
    ->groupBy('template_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you. But i found out something what is not clear for me, when i wanted to extend the query and i add one more parameter called lets say `title` i was not able to execute query until i changed mysql config: mysql.strict => from true to false. The error message: `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column &#039;id&#039; which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.` Do you think it is ok to use change the value of strict property to false?

Comment: @Gocek1 it really depends on the one who handles the production servers. If it's you - it's fine, I guess. Regardless, you can tweak the query to handle that without this property.